# Extracting list-elements that appear more than once

Tags: r

I have the following list:

```
tmp <- list(c(1,2,1,2,11,29),
            c(2,3,2,3,20,21),
            c(10,11,12,13,14,15))

names(tmp) <- c("ID1","ID2","ID3")
```

If we write out each of the 5 vectors of this list, we then have

```
(1,2,10)
(2,3,11)
(1,2,12)
(2,3,13)
(11,20,14)
(29,21,15)
```

Note that the combination `(1,2,X)` and `(2,3,Y)` appear twice, both of them. I would like to extract those vectors, where the first two elements appear `n` times. So for `n=2` we would get

```
(1,2,10)
(1,2,12)
```

and

```
(2,3,11)
(2,3,13)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We loop through the `list` elements, check whether the `vector` elements are `%in%` 'one' ('two'), get the `sum` of the logical vectors, check if it is greater than or equal to 2, then use this index to subset the `list` elements

```
tmp[sapply(tmp, function(x) sum(x %in% tmp$one)>=2)]
tmp[sapply(tmp, function(x) sum(x %in% tmp$two)>=2)]
```

It can be combined in a single call

```
lapply(tmp[c("one", "two")], function(x) tmp[sapply(tmp, function(y) sum(y %in% x)>=2)])
#$one
#$one$one
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

#$one$four
#[1]  1  2 15 16 17 18


#$two
#$two$two
#[1]  7  8  9 10 11 12

#$two$five
#[1]  7  8 15 16 17 18

#$two$<NA>
#[1]  7  8 20 21 22 23
```

Based on the output showed, it can be also a `matrix`

```
lapply(tmp[c("one", "two")], function(x) 
         do.call(rbind, tmp[sapply(tmp, function(y) sum(y %in% x)>=2)]))
```

---

In general, if we want to compare elements of `list` for any number of combinations, `combn` can be used

```
lst1 <- combn(tmp, 3, FUN = list)
lst1[sapply(lst1, function(x) length(Reduce(intersect, x))>=3)]
```

#### Update

Based on the new question

```
library(purrr)
tmp1 <- transpose(tmp) %>%
            map(unlist, use.names = FALSE)
lst1 <- combn(tmp1, 2, FUN = list)
lapply(lst1[sapply(lst1, function(x) length(Reduce(intersect, x))==2)], 
               function(x) do.call(rbind, x))
#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2   10
#[2,]    1    2   12

#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    3   11
#[2,]    2    3   13
```

Comment: @BillyJean  I am getting the same output you showed there.  Please check the update

Comment: if I write `==2` then the output should be (according to the example in the OP) `(1,2,3,4,5,6)` and `(1,2,15,16,17,18)`. That's not what I am getting now

Comment: @BillyJean It is a `list` of elements, if you check the update, it can be combined to a matrix.  or else, I am not following what kind of structure you are looking for

Comment: I found an error in my OP.... sorry. Should I reformulate it or close the thread and make a new one? Sorry again

Comment: I did that now, thanks for your patience, much appreciated

Comment: @BillyJean Updated the post.  Let me know if there is any further changes

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the requirement is for `n = 2`.

Create an artificial variable summarizing the two vectors (use `sep="\b"` to be more confident of uniqueness)

```
idx = paste(tmp[["ID1"]], tmp[["ID2"]], sep="\b")
```

Create a table summarizing the occurrence of each label, select the elements of the table that satisfy the condition, and get their names

```
nms = names(which(table(idx) == n))
```

Determine which elements you'd like to `keep`, then subset each element of `tmp`

```
keep = idx %in% nms
lapply(tmp, `[`, keep)
```

As a function with a little generality

```
fun = function(lst, n, op = `==`, key = 1:2) {
    idx = paste(lst[[ key[1] ]], lst[[ key[2] ]], sep="\b")
    keep = idx %in% names(which(op(table(idx), n)))
    lapply(lst, `[`, keep)
}
```